# What is Wudu and how to make it?

Tags: quran, wudu, conversion

I'm 12 and I'm converting into Islam here in a 3 or 4 months. How do I make Wudu? What is it? Also, can I read the Q'uran? I just want to be closer with Allah/god.

Answer (score 1):

Salam (peace be with you) Lydea! So glad to hear such great news!

You can actually find all these questions answered with a quick Google search, but I'll help you out.

Wudu is an Arabic word meaning ablution. It's a ritual where a Muslim cleanses certain parts of their body for prayer.

Those 7 parts include (note that these are in order):

1. Wash your hands up to the wrists thoroughly three times.
2. Rinse your mouth three times, swirling the water around, and rinse your nose three times, blowing the water out using the left hand to remove the water from your nose.
3. Wash your face three times, from the hairline to the chin and from ear to ear, making sure the whole face, eyebrows, under the nose and lips are washed
4. Wash your arms and hands from your fingertips up to your elbows three times. It is essential to remove anything that could prevent the water from reaching the skin i.e. dough, mud, paint, etc.
5. Wipe your head starting with your hands at the front of your head, bringing them to the back of your head and then back to the front again. With regards to a woman’s hair, she should wipe it from the front of her head to the roots of the hair at the nape of her neck. She does not have to wipe the entire length of her hair.
6. Wipe your ears by putting your index fingers in your ears and wiping the back with your thumbs. It's preferable to use freshwater for this.
7. Wash your feet three times up to the ankles, making sure to wipe in between your toes with your little finger. Don’t forget the back of your ankles.

And yes you can read Qur'an. Since you're, God willing, going to be a new Muslim, you most likely don't know Arabic yet so the best way to learn about God better is by reading the English Qur'an.

You can easily do this by Googling "English translation of the Qur'an" or even downloading an English Qur'an app on your phone.

Remember, since you're going to be a new Muslim, it's advised to Google your questions that most likely have been answered already online before coming here. This site is for specific queries of Islam that really haven't been asked online.

Here are a few resources to look into: 
-[A guide for a new Muslim](https://www.icorlando.org/pdfs/en_A_guide_for_the_new_Muslim.pdf) 
-[A brief illustrated guide towards understanding Islam](https://www.islamreligion.com/ebooks/islam-guide.pdf)

May God bless and help you on your journey!